# Trouble installing Ubuntu 12.04 on Mac PowerPC G5

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, mac, yaboot

Disclaimer: I know very little about doing anything on a computer other than regular updates and downloading music software. This is my first OS replacement, so I may be a little frustrating to some.

I'm very new to Ubuntu and not entirely sure if what I'm doing is even possible on my G5, but I can't really seem to find a straight answer on any of the forums I've come across. I was given a PowerPC G5.

*Specs:*

Model Name: Power Mac G5
   Model Identifier:  PowerMac11,2
    Processor Name:   PowerPC G5 (1.0)
   Processor Speed:   2 GHz
   Number of CPUs:    2
   L2 Cache (per CPU):    1 MB
   Memory:    8 GB
   Bus Speed: 1 GHz
   Boot ROM Version:  5.2.7f1
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 6600 LE
Running OS X 10.5.8

I've tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 alternate PowerPC and 12.04 desktop powerpc and the farthest I ever get in either of them is the black yaboot screen. It prompts me to press "Enter" and when I do it flashes to a white screen with black writing and then nothing... except my computer sounds like it's about to explode....

Things I've done to fix it based on somewhat similar problems on other forums:

- Make sure the DVI cable is in the primary port.
- Try to see if my GPU is supported. (couldn't find a straight answer)
- Typed in different commands to try to change the video to "nomodeset". (don't know if I was even doing this right)

---

Thanks for your replies. I just tried 14.04 32-bit and 64-bit and the same with 16.04 and neither of them worked.. Restarted my computer, held down "c" and nothing for both. It's like the superdrive isn't able to read the disc?? Are there steps that im missing? Is it worth the hassle?

---

Ok so I finally got Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my computer. I had to do a NetBoot and download the GUI from the terminal. Now I'm running into the issue where as soon as I log in all I see is just the normal wallpaper and no apps or menus or anything.

Answer (score -1):

did you try to install it as a main Operating system on the specific computer?

download ubuntu 14.04 and try again to install it!
what device did you use to install ubuntu?

Comment: The device information that you're asking about is included in the question in the *Specs* section. As long as you're recommending installing a different version of Ubuntu, why not recommend the latest version?

Comment: you can use the latest one. there is not gonna be any problems as long as you follow correctly the steps of installation but i found a video that shows your computer with 14.04 version.

Comment: Is there a 14.04 for powerpc?

Comment: @karel The latest Ubuntu for powerpc is 12.04. There is Lubuntu 14.04 for powerpc too, but no Ubuntu.